# Unidentifiable error in SQL syntax, thrown when trying to store a procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am getting an error when I try to enter the following procedure using the phpMyAdmin SQL box. I'm pretty sure the syntax is correct though!

ERROR:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 

')
BEGIN
    UPDATE decks
    JOIN amount ON amount.DeckName = de' at line 1
```

SQL SYNTAX:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCard(IN aCard varChar)
BEGIN
    UPDATE decks 
    JOIN amount ON amount.DeckName = decks.DeckName 
    SET decks.DeckTotal = decks.DeckTotal - amount.Amount
    WHERE amount.CardName = aCard ;  

    UPDATE types t1
    JOIN cards ON cards.TypeName = t1.TypeName 
    JOIN Amount ON amount.CardName = cards.CardName
    SET t1.TypeTotal = t1.TypeTotal - amount.Amount
    WHERE amount.CardName = aCard ; 

    DELETE  
    FROM amount 
    WHERE cardName = aCard;

    DELETE  
    FROM cards 
    WHERE cardName = aCard;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing the varchar length, like `IN aCard VARCHAR(32)`

Comment: Does phpmyadmin now respect the `DELIMITER` keyword? That's a feature of the command line MySQL client, not a language feature and in the past, phpmyadmin had its own form field for specifying a delimiter.

Comment: Seems very identifiable to me

Comment: Yes I am. Thank you Michael Berkowski.